# Gesture Recogniser for all events

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have this piece of code

```
let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
window?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

It only recognizes Tap (as its tap gesture recognizer), however I want some recognizer to work for all, scroll, pinch, etc.

*Also at later point of time I am removing this recognizer*.

I read touches began, but how to use it on `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow`?

And how to remove that touches began later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to monitor all touch event then you can subclass UITapGestureRecognizer, this link should help: [Monitoring all iOS touches](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/monitoring-all-ios-touches/)